# Codes to add multiple new columns based on row strings of a column from one file matched to that present in multiple columns of another file

Tags: python, r, bash

I'm very basic to writing complex codes for a situation like the one here. I have 2 files with different number of columns and rows:  File_1.csv & File_2.csv. The 3rd column 'Structure' in File_2.csv has combined row strings from 5th 'Structure_1', 6th 'Structure_2', 7th 'Structure_3' columns of File_1.csv. File_1.csv can have multiple rows with same row strings of those three 'Structure_1', 'Structure_2', 'Structure_3' columns, while File_2.csv 'Structure' column only have the row strings occuring once. Now I would like to use the 4th column 'Barcodes' of File_2.csv to the File_1 every time it matches with the 'Structure' column of File_2.csv, and add three new columns named 'Barcode_1', 'Barcode_2', 'Barcode_3' at the end of File_1.csv, which would correspond to their 'Structure_1', 'Structure_2', 'Structure_3' strings and their position in File_1.csv. Since the row strings of 'Structure_1', 'Structure_2', 'Structure_3' in File_1.csv can be present multiple times it can be the case that the row strings for 'Barcode_1', 'Barcode_2', 'Barcode_3' are added more than once to File_1.csv as well. Please find the 2 files & the example File_3_output.csv file.

[File_1.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOoxq.png)
[File_2.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtUrj.png)
[File_3_output.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYT9R.png) Any Bash or Python or R codes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these .CSV files or what? Where does barcode `sssss` come from? Is it the case that you just want to add columns to file_1 which use file_2 to map from the structures to the associated barcodes? If so easy using Python Pandas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: File 3 seems to be incorrectly uploaded (similar to output). It would be more convenient to format your post so that we can understand all conditions more easily.

Comment: @user19077881 yes, they all are .csv files and edited on the original post. sssss barcode corresponds to unique Structure that was not captured on uploaded FIle_2.csv. For clarity, I have omitted sssss with nnnnn. Yes, i just want to add new columns containing barcodes to File_1.csv. upon mapping its 3 structure columns using File_2.csv structure row strings. Would you mind sharing the codes to work around on Python Panda?

Comment: @basti Sorry for the confusion. File_3 is nothin but the output. Plz see the formatted post.

Comment: @Community My specific problem is to map multiple columns (Structure_1 .._2, ..._3) of File_1.csv with strings of a single column (Structure) from File_2.csv. However I want to add 3 new columns (Barcode_1, .._2, .._3) with strings from a totally different column (Barcode) from File_2.csv upon mapping.

Comment: Verbal descriptions are often/usually ambiguous. Readers need data and code to look at to understand the particular issues in your problem. A good question will be easy for readers to copy/paste the minimal amount of code that illustrates the problem, with 1) a small sample inputs (or processes ) , 2) required output or action from that input 3) current code, 4) current behavior (output) of that code, 5) exact text of error messages. Consider updating your question so readers can quickly experience your problem. Please read about [mcve]. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly read a .CSV file into a pandas dataframe using pd.read_csv. In the code below I created two sample dataframes as I do not have your .CSV files. There are numerous ways to do the mapping (such as by merging the dataframes) but code below creates and then uses a mapping dictionary. This should be enough to get you going. The result dataframe can then be written out as a .CSV.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"struct1": ['CDAB', 'ACEG', 'KLMN'],
                   "struct2": ['ACEG', 'XAYBZ', 'ACEG']
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"struct": ['CDAB', 'ACEG', 'KLMN', 'XAYBZ'],
                    "barcodes": ['111', '222', '333', '444']
                    })

print(df1)
print(df2)

d = dict(df2[['struct', 'barcodes']].values)

df1['barcodes_1']= df1['struct1'].map(d)
df1['barcodes_2']= df1['struct2'].map(d)

print(df1)
```

which gives

```
  struct1 struct2
0    CDAB    ACEG
1    ACEG   XAYBZ
2    KLMN    ACEG

  struct barcodes
0   CDAB      111
1   ACEG      222
2   KLMN      333
3  XAYBZ      444

  struct1 struct2 barcodes_1 barcodes_2
0    CDAB    ACEG        111        222
1    ACEG   XAYBZ        222        444
2    KLMN    ACEG        333        222
```

Comment: Great, the codes solved the problem. Thanks a lot!